# Fluid Layout (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I am in the process of creating a site that i would like to be responsive. I am using Twitter bootstrap to assist with this. I have managed to get the majority of it working but a few elements within the site are not playing ball. Now maybe im just missing the obvious but would appreciate it if someone could point out where I have gone wrong so that 1) i can correct the issues and 2) learn from my mistakes.

The site is at http://growing-mist-5023.herokuapp.com/ and the part im trying to fix is the polaroids across the center of the page under the slider. All constructive criticism welcomed as I am trying to learn ( albeit from my mistakes) and any suggestions welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace `<div class="row">` with `<div class="row-fluid">` in the 2nd level parent of your .polaroid

I don't think you can keep the same layout under 768px (picture below with 480px)

[image: 480px width]

I would recommend you to use another class on the top of the .span3 and use media queries to overide the behaviour of the .span3 under 768 to create a centered 2x2.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was concerned over the sizing of each polaroid? or will row-fluid solve this

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example media query  to create this centered 2x2 look? would be much appreciated

Comment: @Richlewis No problem, but I can promise it's gonna be done today.

Comment: thats ok, whenever you can, appreciate anything you can do, i am reading about media queries at the moment but this is a little to complex i feel at present

Comment: @Richlewis I have created a new question to look a bit more generic,  answer and explanations are here :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11263096/1416911

Comment: thank you so much, great explanation and detail, really helps me out

Comment: I know this is off subject but do you know how to center an image in a span within a row-fluid?

Comment: @Richlewis simply add the class .thumbnail