# twitter boostrap (responsive) : .span3 taking .span6 full width behaviour when width between 320px and 797px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries, html

With twitter bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css, `.span*` become equivalent to a `.span12` under `768px`.

This behaviour is perfectly fine when text is embedded, but for pictures it make sense to use a `2x2` layout between `4x1` and `1x4`.

How to obtain this `2x2` layout from `767px` to `320px`?

**768px wide (4x1)**
[image: 4x .span3 with 768px width]

**767px wide (1x4)**
[image: 4x .span3 with 767px width]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                <p>2</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                <p>4</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/jWcdS/

---

**Notes:** This question is inspired by the request asked in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223746/1416911)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row-fluid .thumbnails .span3 {
        width:48.6188%;
        margin-left: 2.76243%;        
        float:left;
    }
    .row-fluid .thumbnails .span3:nth-child(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/jWcdS/1/

**500px wide (2x2)**

[image: 4x .span3 with 500px width]

**319px wide (1x4)**

[image: 4x .span3 with 319px width]

**Explanations:**

[Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) can be used to override twitter bootstrap between 320px and 767px by using `@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px)`

`.row-fluid .thumbnails .span3` has been used over a `.span3{ ... }` or `.row-fluid .span3{ ... }` for the following reasons:

- 3 classes make enough [priority](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector) to override `.row-fluid .span3` from bootstrap.css
- adding `.thumbnails` between `.row-fluid` and `.span3` will not affect the other `.row-fluid .span3` used for the layout.

The `width:48.6188%;` and `margin-left: 2.76243%;` correspond the the value given to a `.row-fluid .span6`

The `float:left;` overrides the `float:none`

The pseudo class `nth-child(2n+1)` has been used with `margin-left: 0;` to remove the left margin on the `.row-fluid .thumbnails .span3` ending up on the left side of the page (1 and 3).

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I found I needed to add other declarations from the Bootstrap ".row-fluid [class*="span"]" rule, namely: *margin-left: 2.074468085106383%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; - I was doing this for 3 columns though.